# agGrid with Angular, using agRichSelectCellEditor

Tags: ag-grid

I have an agGrid populated with Employee records in JSON format from my web service.

```
[
   { 
     id: 123,
     firstName: 'Mike',
     lastName: 'Jones',
     countryId: 1001,
     DOB: '1980-01-01T00:00:00',
     . . .
   }
```

I have a second web service returning a list of country codes:

```
[ 
    { id: 1000, name: 'France' },
    { id: 1001, name: 'Spain' },
    { id: 1002, name: 'Belguim' }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is get my agGrid to have a column showing the user's details, including the *name* of their country, and when they edit this cell, a list of country codes will appear, where they can select one, and it'll update the record with the id of that country.

Basic stuff, no ?

But has anyone managed to get agGrid to successfully use the "agRichSelectCellEditor" to do this successfully ?

```
  { headerName: 'Country', width: 120, field: 'countryId', editable: true, 
      cellEditor:'agRichSelectCellEditor',

      cellEditorParams: { 
          // This tells agGrid that when we edit the country cell, we want a popup to be displayed
          // showing (just) the names of the countries in our reference data
          values: listOfCountries.map(s => s.name)
      },

      //  The "cellRenderer" tells agGrid to display the country name in each row, rather than the
      //  numeric countryId value
      cellRenderer: (params) => listOfCountries.find(refData => refData.id == params.data.countryId)?.name,

      valueSetter: function(params) {
        //  When we select a value from our drop down list, this function will make sure 
        //  that our row's record receives the "id" (not the text value) of the chosen selection.
        params.data.countryId = listOfCountries.find(refData => refData.name == params.newValue)?.id;
        return true;
    }  
  },
```

My code seems to be *almost* correct.. it manages to:

- display the country *name* in each row of the agGrid
- display a popup, listing the country names, from our "list of countries" array
- when I select an item in the popup, it successfully updates the `countryId` field with the (numeric) id value of my chosen country

The only problem is that at the top of the popup, it shows the `countryId` value, rather than the user's current country name.

[image]

Has anyone managed to get this to work ?

The only workaround I could come up with was to override the CSS on this popup and hide that top element:

```
.ag-rich-select-value
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

It works... but you no longer get to see what your previously selected value was.

[image]

(I really wish the agGrid website had some decent, real-life, working Angular examples...  or at least let developers post comments on there, to help each other out.)

Answer (score 4):

The solution was to use a `valueGetter`, rather than a `cellRenderer`:

```
 { 
    headerName: 'Country', width: 120, field: 'countryId', editable: true, 
    cellEditor:'agRichSelectCellEditor',

    cellEditorParams: { 
        // This tells agGrid that when we edit the country cell, we want a popup to be displayed
        // showing (just) the names of the countries in our reference data
        values: listOfCountries.map(s => s.name)
    },

    valueSetter: function(params) {
        //  When we select a value from our drop down list, this function will make sure
        //  that our row's record receives the "id" (not the text value) of the chosen selection.
        params.data.countryId = listOfCountries.find(refData => refData.name == params.newValue)?.id;
        return true;
    }, 

    valueGetter: function(params) {
        //  We don't want to display the raw "countryId" value.. we actually want 
        //  the "Country Name" string for that id.
        return listOfCountries.find(refData => refData.id == params.data.countryId)?.name;
    }
},
```

I hope this is useful...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my similar situation (id:name pairs in a list, but not using `Angular` though) working without the problem you mentioned above, and without a `valueGetter/valueSetter` and only a renderer. The benefit is that you don't need to double click the cell to see the list, the cell appears as a selection box always, and you avoid a bug should the user double click the cell when the list is displayed.

The renderer is a lot clunkier than I was wanting (one line like yours) and it didn't seem that aggrid had built in support for this pretty basic function (and I already have spent enough time on this).

Anyway, this is what I had, which at least works, but keen to see further improvements on it. (You will need to at least change 2 lines for the option related code since my `defaultValue` object is specific to me).

The column definition:

```
{field: 'defaultValueID', headerName: "Default Value", cellEditor:'agRichSelectCellEditor', cellRenderer: defaultValueRenderer}
```

And the renderer code:

```js
    function defaultValueRenderer(params) {
        var input = document.createElement("select");
        // allow it to be cleared
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.innerHTML = '[None]';
        option.value = null;
        input.appendChild(option);

        for (var i=0; i < defaultValueList.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.innerHTML = defaultValueList[i].name;
            option.value = defaultValueList[i].gltID;
            input.appendChild(option);
        }

        input.value = params.value;
        input.onchange = function() {
            params.setValue(this.value);
            params.data.defaultValueID = this.value;
        }
        input.style="width: 100%; height: 100%"; // default looks too small
        return input;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Is Example Of agRichSelectCellEditor...

```
{
            headerName: 'Dropdown', field: 'dropdown',
            cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
            width: 140,          
            editable: true,

            cellEditorParams: (params) => {
            values: Get All Dropdown List Like ["Hello","Hiii","How Are You?"]
            },

            valueSetter: (params) => {
              if (params.newValue) {
               params.data.dropdown= params.newValue;
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler solution: use `cellEditorParams` `formatValue`, along with `valueFormatter`

```
        {
        field: 'foo',
        cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
        cellEditorParams: {
            values: [1,2,3, 4, other ids... ],
            formatValue: (id: number): string => this.getLabelFromId(value)
        },
        valueFormatter: (params: ValueFormatterParams): string => this.getLabelFromId(params.value as number)
    }
```